# NPM won't automatically set up cmdlet's for me?

Tags: linux, windows, npm, command, powershell-cmdlet

this is the first this ever happened to me.

I am trying to install a documentation generator ([docma](https://onury.io/docma/)) and for some reason I follow everything they say in the docs and can't execute 'docma' or 'docma serve', it says it's not recognized as a cmdlet, tried it on my Linux machine and it also isn't recognized as a command, so there's no way for me to serve my documentation and the developer stopped supporting that years ago.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I should add that I don't get a node_modules folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `package.json` file for your project, create one:

```
npm init
```

(If you don't care about what the contents of the `package.json` file are, then you can accept all the defaults with `npm init -y` rather than answer the questions the command will ask you.)

The documentation says to install `docma` in a project like this:

```
npm i docma -D
```

Do that. That will create a `node_modules` directory if you don't already have one.

From there, all the commands in the `docma` documentation can be executed from the command line if you precede them with `npx`.  So where it says `docma`, you can use `npx docma`. And where it says `docma serve`, you can use `npx docma serve`. (You will need to be in your project directory for this to work!)

Another solution would be to install `docma` globally (`npm i docma -g`) but that has its own risks and complications (such as requiring elevated privileges in some situations). What I've described above is (IMO) safer and better.